# Increase replication factor of topics

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a 6 broker cluster, and planning to increase this to 12 node cluster
At the moment we all our topics have replica factor of 3 however after the estate expansion we are planning to change replica factor to 4.

We have close to 1k topics, each with 32 or 50 partitions.

We are using opensource kafka 2.8

Can anyone advise any automated script, where the proposed json payload is created with replica factor of 4 and the replicas are evenly distributed across all 12 brokers in the cluster

Answer (score 0):

Features of [Cruise Control](https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control) include the three operations you're looking to do

- Add brokers
- Rebalance the cluster
- Adjust replication factor

Comment: Agree, however I would need to do this using native kafka shell scripts and any custom scripts

Comment: Native Kafka tools don't do any of this automatically, thus why LinkedIn created Cruise Control to manage their own Kafka clusters.

Comment: Ok, Can you suggest how can we tackle this? We wouldn't be able to get cruise control in our enterprise yet, hence any ideas how can we automate this?

Comment: You'd need to write the code yourself to generate and run JSON compatible with `kafka-reassign-partitions` CLI, or the equivalent Java classes that uses. That's the only way

Comment: Kafka also has no tools to add brokers. You'd use tools like Terraform or Ansible for that.

Comment: Correct, we are using CHEF for config management

Comment: That's a good start, but I have no other suggestions for you. I know Datadog published a `kafka-kit` repo on Github, I think Yelp has one as well, and that has some scripts you can look at, but anything you're looking for will require extra code / downloads outside of Kafka itself.